# Proof that the function $f(x)=d(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity, epsilon-delta

Consider a metric space $(M, {\rm d})$ 
and $y$  fixed in $M$.

I want to prove that the function $f$ defined by $f(x)\colon={\rm d}(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous.

So I know that if this function is uniformly continuous, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if the ${\rm d}(x_1,x_2)<\delta$, then this implies the ${\rm d}(f(x_1),f(x_2))<\epsilon$.

So for all epsilon greater than zero, there exists a delta greater than zero such that ${\rm d}(x_1,x_2)<\delta \implies |{\rm d}(x_1,y)-{\rm d}(x_2,y)|<\epsilon$.

I can't figure out how to manipulate this equation to solve for delta!! 
I tried using the triangle inequality but it gets me nowhere. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \epsilon$. Take $x_1,x_2 \in M$ such that ${\rm d}(x_1,x_2) < \delta$. Then: $$|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| = |{\rm d}(x_1,y)-{\rm d}(x_2,y)| \leq {\rm d}(x_1,x_2) < \delta = \epsilon.$$

---

Obs.: by the triangle inequality, we have that $${\rm d}(x_1,y)\leq {\rm d}(x_1,x_2)+{\rm d}(x_2, y)\implies {\rm d}(x_1,y)-{\rm d}(x_2,y)\leq {\rm d}(x_1,x_2).$$
Swapping $x_1$ and $x_2$ you get: $ {\rm d}(x_2,y)-{\rm d}(x_1,y)\leq {\rm d}(x_2,x_1) = {\rm d}(x_1,x_2).$ This way, the inequality $|{\rm d}(x_1,y)-{\rm d}(x_2,y)| \leq {\rm d}(x_1,x_2)$ follows from the definition of absolute value.

Comment: why can you swap x1 and x2?

Comment: It is because what I've done earlier is valid for **any** points $x_1,x_2$. It was a quick way to saying that you can repeat the same argument. Like when books say "analogously, yadda yadda yadda". In details, what I omitted was: $${\rm d}(x_2,y)\leq {\rm d}(x_2,x_1)+{\rm d}(x_1, y)\implies {\rm d}(x_2,y)-{\rm d}(x_1,y)\leq {\rm d}(x_2,x_1).$$

Do compare with what I've done before.

Comment: i see, that makes sense. Thanks!! how did you come up with this so quickly?

Comment: Practice dealing with these problems, I reckon. I think I'm a little biased, since I'm taking a summer course about metric spaces here (:

Comment: i hope to get that good at this one day! thanks a lot

Comment: Don't mind it! Oh, and you can accept one of the answers (whichever helped you most), so this question doesn't stay floating in the unanswered queue (green checkmark). This helps keeping the site more organized. If you need any more help just say it (:

Comment: De nada! You speak portuguese? haha

Comment: pouco haha i just noticed your profile says universidade de sao paulo:)

Comment: You can add me on facebook if you want to chat :)
(us flooding the post in comments here is not so welcomed by community, soon they'll delete a few comments)

Answer (score 3):

You have to show that for *fixed* $\;m\in X$= the metric space, the function $\;f(x):=d(m,x)\;$ is unif. continuous, so you have to show that

$$\forall\,\epsilon>0\;\exists\,\delta >0\;\;s.t.\;\;d(x,y)<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|=|d(m,x)-d(m,y)|<\epsilon$$

But all you have to do then is use the triangle inequality and some symmetry:

$$d(m,x)\le d(m,y)+d(y,x)\implies |d(m,x)-d(m,y)|\le d(x,y)$$

and take now $\;\delta=\epsilon$ .

Comment: It might confuse OP that you changed the fixed point to $m$, and used $y$ as variable, since he was using $y$ as a fixed point. I don't know. Just my opinion, though (:

Comment: Indeed so, @IvoTerek . Yet I began answering this question before you edited it and didn't even see he did so. I think though that someone dealing with this must already be able to overcome that. Thank you.

Comment: thanks guys this very helpful